# How can I bridge Twilio PSTN Voice Conference to Twilio Video Room?

Tags: video, twilio

I have read these articles
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/conference
https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/understanding-video-rooms
https://www.twilio.com/blog/now-you-can-add-programmable-voice-participants-video-group-rooms
but I still struggle to understand how can I bridge Twilio PSTN Voice Conference to Twilio Video Room?

I see the information in the documentation that

The `<Connect>` verb is designed to connect individual PSTN phone calls into a Video Room. This functionality should not be used to bridge a Programmable Voice Conference with a Video Room. This is an unsupported use case and it can fail in unexpected ways.

So I guess, I can join individual participants to Twilio Video Room.

However, I need them wait until the host starts Twilio Video Room.

Is this possible to achieve?

To summarize, I have two problems.

Is there any better way to bridge a Programmable Voice Conference with a Video Room than connecting every individual PSTN caller through `<connect>` verb?
How can I make PSTN callers wait until the host starts the Twilio Video Room?

Comment: @devin-rader Hello, could you please validate my guess answer to my second question and check my first question?

Comment: @marcos-placona Hello, could you please validate my guess answer to my second question and check my first question?

Comment: @philnash Hello, could you please validate my guess answer to my second question and check my first question?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an option to make PSTN Callers wait until the host starts the Twilio Video Room.

When PSTN Participant joins, TwiML app should return a Say command with a waiting message with an infinite loop (loop = 0), which will repeat the message 1000 times.

Then [Update a Call Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#update-a-call-resource) can be used either to terminate the call by timeout or execute the `<connect>` verb to connect the participant to the `<room>`